# ActiveMq configuration

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-camel

I have an activeMQ server and I'm using camel to consume the messages.
Current config is 25 concurrent consumers eagerly taking as many messages as they can per session, but I need to limit the number of messages consumed in one session by each consumer to 1. I couldn't find such config anywhere. Can someone point me the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your goal is to get a better spread of message across consumers, then you should lower the queue prefetch limit

see http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html